# android NDK - make standalone toolchain fails

Tags: android, android-ndk, toolchain

I tried to make a standalone Android NDK toolchain on Linux 64 bit:

~/build/android-ndk-r9/build/tools $ ./make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-14 --ndk-dir=/home/user/build/android-ndk-r9 --system=linux-x86_64 --install-dir=/home/user/build/android-14-toolchain
Auto-config: --toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-4.6
Copying prebuilt binaries...

No files are actually copied. Something goes wrong. The NDK ist the latest release r9.
How can I run the script so that the files get copied to the installation directory?

Comment: I added the following lines to the make-standalone-toolchain.sh:     # Create temporary directory
NDK_TMPDIR=/tmp
TMPDIR=$NDK_TMPDIR/standalone/$TOOLCHAIN_NAME     Now I have another problem: limits.h can't be found by ./configure if I try to compile my project: /home/stefan/build/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/include-fixed/limits.h:169:61: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A suggestion:  Use the --verbose option if you haven't already done so; it will tell you in which stage the error occurs.

Here are the options I ran to make a standalone toolchain targeting android-14 and arm-linux-androideabi-4.7

```
    sudo sh make-standalone-toolchain.sh --verbose --toolchain=x86-4.7\
    --install-dir=/project/arm-cc --ndk-dir=/project/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9\
    --platform=android-14
```

Comment: --verbose made me realise I was using android 8 when min supported was 9...

Comment: --verbose helped me to realize I needed python